# Create a server on Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, backend

I create a server on `Node.js`. I use SQL server. I want to creata a sql query that find book by the given input. When I wrote my query error was:

> name: 'ERROR',
> handlerName: 'onErrorMessage',
> number: 207,
> state: 1,
> class: 16,
> message: "Invalid column name '%@param4%'.",
> serverName: 'DESKTOP-PQSULQS\SQLEXPRESS',
> procName: '',
> lineNumber: 1

This is a searchMethod:

```
async function searchBook(input){
    let result = await sql.query `SELECT * FROM dbo.Books WHERE Title = ${input} OR Kind = ${input} OR Author = ${input} OR Title LIKE "%${input}%"` ;
    return result.recordset;
}
```

I try to resolve this problem. But I don't know why server throw this exception.Any advices?

Comment: The query seems to be wrong. You're missing quotes. I would recommend: (1) Write and run the query against the database. (2) Copy the working query and run it with javascript. (3) Modify the query to receive your input parameter. (4) Investigate how to prevent SQL Injections because that format will welcome those attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main issue with shared code sample is each nvarchar column value should to be encased in a single quotation `''` if you gone use template literal with static vales.

then the code will be as the following:

```
async function searchBook(input){
    let result = await sql.query(`SELECT * FROM dbo.Books WHERE Title = '${input}' OR Kind = '${input}' OR Author = '${input}' OR Title LIKE '%${input}%'`);
    return result.recordset;
}
```

but this code has [sql injection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#sql-injection) vulnerability so to prevent it. use parameters to overcome this issue.

so your code will be as the following:

```
 async function searchBook(input){
    let request = new sql.Request();
    request.input('input', sql.NVarChar, input);
    let result = await request.query(`SELECT * FROM dbo.Books WHERE Title = @input OR Kind = @input OR Author = @input OR Title LIKE '%' + @input + '%'`);
    return result.recordset;
}
```

Comment: When I try this error message is: Must declare the scalar variable "@input".'

Comment: @BlagoDamqnov please try the updated solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the construction of the request.

The use of parameters should solve the problem.

```js
async function searchBook(input){
    let result = await sql.query`SELECT * FROM dbo.Books WHERE Title = @title OR Kind = @kind OR Author = @author OR Title LIKE "%" + @title + "%"`,
    {
        params: {
            title: input,
            kind: input,
            author: input
        }
    };
    return result.recordset;
}
```